# Making an dynamic <And><Or> Caml Query

Tags: caml-query

I am Trying to write an Dynamic Caml Query.

I did it like This:

```
CamlQuery qry = new CamlQuery();
        string qryStatus = "";
        string qryCategory = "";

        foreach (RiskStatus sta in filter.Status)
        {
            if (sta == null)
                continue;

            qryStatus = "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Status' /><Value Type='Text'>" + sta.Name + "</Value></Eq>" + qryStatus;
        }

        if (filter.Status.Length >= 2)
        {
            qryStatus = "<Or>" + qryStatus + "</Or>";
        }

        foreach (RiskCategory ctg in filter.Categories)
        {
            if (ctg == null)
                continue;

            qryCategory = "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Category' /><Value Type='Text'>" + ctg.Name + "</Value></Eq>" + qryCategory;
        }

        if (filter.Categories.Length >= 2)
        {
            qryCategory = "<Or>" + qryCategory + "</Or>";
        }

        qry.ViewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>"
                    + "<Query>"
                    + "   <Where>"
                    + "     <And>"
                    + qryStatus
                    + qryCategory
                    + "     </And>"
                    + "   </Where>"
                    + "</Query>"
                    + "</View>";
        return qry;
```

I use this Test values:

```
CategoryArray[0] = new TestCategory { Name = "(2) TestCategory2" };
StatusArray[0] = new TestStatus { Name = "(1) TestStatus1" };

CategoryArray[1] = new TestCategory { Name = "(3) TestCategory3" };
StatusArray[1] = new TestStatus { Name = "(2) TestStatus2" };
```

This is the Result I get:

```
<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
<Query>   
<Where>     
    <And>
        <Or>
            <Eq><FieldRef Name='Status' /><Value Type='Text'>(2) TestStatus2</Value></Eq>
            <Eq><FieldRef Name='Status' /><Value Type='Text'>(1) TestStatus1</Value></Eq>
        </Or>
        <Or>
            <Eq><FieldRef Name='Category' /><Value Type='Text'>(3) TestCategory3</Value></Eq>
            <Eq><FieldRef Name='Category' /><Value Type='Text'>(2) TestCategory2</Value></Eq>
        </Or>     
    </And>   
</Where>
</Query>
</View>
```

It works fine But if I add a third value I get the exception "Cannot complete this action.\n\nPlease try again."

Added Value:

```
  StatusArray[2] = new TestStatus { Name = "(3) Status3" };
```

Result:

```
<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
<Query>   
<Where>     
    <And>
        <Or>
            <Eq><FieldRef Name='Status' /><Value Type='Text'>(3) TestStatus3</Value></Eq>
            <Eq><FieldRef Name='Status' /><Value Type='Text'>(2) TestStatus2</Value></Eq>
            <Eq><FieldRef Name='Status' /><Value Type='Text'>(1) TestStatus3</Value></Eq>
        </Or>
        <Or>
            <Eq><FieldRef Name='Category' /><Value Type='Text'>(3) TestCategory3</Value></Eq>
            <Eq><FieldRef Name='Category' /><Value Type='Text'>(2) TestCategory2</Value></Eq>
        </Or>     
    </And>
```

What am I doing wrong? 
(This is my first time working with Caml Query)

Comment: There is one problem in your last caml query. You have to write</Eq> instead of </eq>. And you can not add 3 fieldref in OR tag.

Comment: So how is it suppose to look like if I want to do it with 3 or more?

Comment: You can get some reference from here -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203821/caml-query-with-nested-ands-and-ors-for-multiple-fields

Comment: doing it like that will make it a lot complicated... I will try. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I had similar kind of requirement, below is the code which I have used previously:

```
enum MergeType { Or, And };

private static string MergeCAMLConditions(List<string> conditions, MergeType type)
{
    if (conditions.Count == 0) return "";

    string typeStart = (type == MergeType.And ? "<And>" : "<Or>");
    string typeEnd = (type == MergeType.And ? "</And>" : "</Or>");

    // Build hierarchical structure
    while (conditions.Count >= 2)
    {
        List<string> complexConditions = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < conditions.Count; i+=2)
        {
            if (conditions.Count == i + 1) // Only one condition left
                complexConditions.Add(conditions[i]);
            else // Two condotions - merge
                complexConditions.Add(typeStart + conditions[i] + conditions[i + 1] + typeEnd);
            }

            conditions = complexConditions;
        }

        return conditions[0];
    }
```

You can call it using:

```
List<string> conditions = new List<string>();
conditions.Add("<Eq><FieldRef Name='Col1' /><Value Type='Text'>value1</Value></Eq>");
conditions.Add("<Eq><FieldRef Name='Col2' /><Value Type='Text'>value2</Value></Eq>");;

string merged = MergeCAMLConditions(conditions, MergeType.And);
```

Answer (score 0):

CAML queries only accept two conditions for logical operators. So you can do

```
<And>
   <Eq>...</Eq>
   <Eq>...</Eq>
</And>
```

but not

```
<And>
   <Eq>...</Eq>
   <Eq>...</Eq>
   <Eq>...</Eq>
</And>
```

Solution is using two s:

```
<And>
  <And>
   <Eq>...</Eq>
   <Eq>...</Eq>
  </And>
   <Eq>...</Eq>
</And>
```

Answer (score 0):

While writing CAML query, you must understand the architecture how it works.

It is pretty simple. You just have to do logical `AND`/`OR` operators.

Any operator must have 2 conditions to combine and test.

**SCENARIO 1 :** This is 1 Operator use with 2 conditions

```
 <Or>
      <Eq><FieldRef Name='Status' /><Value Type='Text'>(3) TestStatus3</Value></Eq>
       <Eq><FieldRef Name='Status' /><Value Type='Text'>(2) TestStatus2</Value></Eq>              
 </Or>
```

**SCENARIO 2 :** This is 2 Operators use with 2 conditions 
From scenario 1 we got operator now along with that we will add another  operator.

```
<And>
    <Or>
      <Eq><FieldRef Name='Status' /><Value Type='Text'>(3) TestStatus3</Value></Eq>
       <Eq><FieldRef Name='Status' /><Value Type='Text'>(2) TestStatus2</Value></Eq>              
    </Or>
    <Eq><FieldRef Name='Status' /><Value Type='Text'>(1) TestStatus1</Value></Eq>                  
</And>
```

Here if you notice, `<OR>` is having two conditions inside it. and that makes 1 condition for outer `<And>`, so we added another condition block parallel to `<OR>` operator. Hence 2 conditions are available for `<AND>`.

Likewise you can build ***n*** number of nested conditions.

PS: If you have only 1 condition, it will not require any operator.